# Docker API - how do I join a network?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-api

this is the documentation for the API: https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/#containers
where you'll see that for the create container method a section of the JSON labelled "NetworkingConfig" is displayed

this section is not described at all and I can't quite figure out how to express what I need, which is the equivalent of a docker-compose:

```
services:
  myservice:
    networks:
      - mynetwork
networks:
  mynetwork:
    external: true
```

how can I do the above programatically?

Comment: When you call `POST containers/create` you pass `NetworkingConfig ` with the network configuration but before you must create the network `POST /networks/create` 


https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/#networks

Comment: ja, I know.  what I don't know are the details (there's no docs for it) so do I just declare the network name e.g. `NetworkingConfig: {EndpointsConfig: {'my-network-name': {}}}`?

Comment: Check my link and search for 'NetworkingConfig' you'll see a json example. 

I`m guiding myself with this docker api impl in python: http://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html along with the official docs to see which parameters are Optional.

Answer (score 1):

so the answer is: it's more complicated than just setting the `NetworkMode` key (which works but only for one network)

to accomplish this: get the network, get the container, bind them together.  something like this (works with dockerode v3.2.4+):

```
const Docker = require('dockerode');
const docker = new Docker();

var net = docker.getNetwork('your-external-network-name');
var cnt = docker.getContainer('your-container-name');

net.connect({Container: cnt.id}, function(err, data) {
  if (!err) console.log('we're good');
})
```